# Win32_GroupUser does not return nested groups from domain security groups

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi

When I use Win32_GroupUser to request members of a local security group, I also get nested domain groups.

E.g. in PowerShell, this query on a member server:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_GroupUser -Filter "GroupComponent='Win32_Group.Domain=`"myserver`",Name=`"LocalTestGroup02`"'" | select PartComponent
```

returns both user- and domain accounts:

```
PartComponent                                                     
-------------                                                     
\\myserver\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain="FLIP",Name="TestGroup"  
\\myserver\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="FLIP",Name="test5"
\\myserver\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="FLIP",Name="test4"
```

The same query, but this time on a domain controller and for membership of a domain security group:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_GroupUser -Filter "GroupComponent='Win32_Group.Domain=`"FLIP`",Name=`"TestGroup2`"'" | select PartComponent
```

only returns the user accounts, despite that its members are exactly the same as the local group above.

```
PartComponent
------------
\\VW-DC01\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="FLIP",Name="test4"                                            
\\VW-DC01\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="FLIP",Name="test5"
```

I see this behavior

- when executed locally and from another server with the  `-ComputerName` parameter
- also with a C# application using System.Management
- on Domain local, Global, and Universal security groups

Does anybody know why that is?
More important, can I change this behavior so I also get to see nested groups in domain groups?

I'm trying to enumerate membership of both local- and domain groups, including members in nested groups.

PS: I know I can also use the Get-ADGroupMember cmdlet, but that's not an option. I only have a WMI connection to the target servers, not LDAP or WinRM.

Thx,

Comment: i would like to see the answer to this as well, but is adsi an option for you? there is a way to specify credentials with it as well if needed

Comment: I'm afraid not, @AnthonyStringer. If I'm not mistaken ADSI uses the LDAP port which is closed. This is a hosting environment. I'm scanning strictly separated customer networks from a management network.

Answer (score 0):

You will only be able to see local groups (i.e. non-domain) on the computer itself, not from the domain controller.
As for seeing nested groups, apart from rolling your own recursive function, you can take a look at [Quest Active Directory tools](http://software.dell.com/products/active-roles/powershell.aspx)
function is `Get-QADGroupMember`

Comment: I don't think that is correct. As my first example shows, I do see domain groups that are member of a local security group. The problem is I do not see domain groups that are member of another domain group.  

Quest Active Directory tools use LDAP just like the native ActiveDirectory PowerShell module, so that is not an option. If it were I could use the Get-ADGroupMember cmdlet.